# Make exception in mode_rewrite rules

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have a script that use payment API and after successful payment send user to a link and script verify the payment.

But I started to use a mod_rewrite to make urls friendly. After editing `.htaccess` many of users email me and say that their payment is nod added to their account.

I am using this rules.

```
# Redirect "ugly" URLs to the desired URLs
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \?a=([^\ ]*)
RewriteRule ^$ /%1? [R=301,L]

# Internally rewrite the "pretty" URL to the real URL
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^$
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} !/admin.php [NC]
RewriteRule ^([^/]*)$ /?a=$1 [L]
```

It basicaly rewrite `hort.com/?a=page` to `hort.com/page`

Payments accept link is

```
 hort.com/index.php?a=return_visa&process=yes
```

and also this one

```
 hort.com/?a=return_visa&process=yes
```

I want something to add to my rules to stop edithing this links.

Comment: hi mr . can you look at this ? @anubhava

Comment: Should `hort.com/?a=return_visa&process=yes` be redirected to `hort.com/return_visa` ?

Comment: no . it should not . the first link accept visa from usa api the secound from russia bank .

Comment: and the point is every time apache rewrite the rule script doesn't answer it . so i need to tell apache to do not take any proccess on this two links.

Comment: when i delete the secound part . the script works fine .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try these rules:

```
# Redirect "ugly" URLs to the desired URLs
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \?a=([^&\s]+)\s
RewriteRule ^(index\.php)?$ /%1? [R=301,L]

# Internally rewrite the "pretty" URL to the real URL
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^$
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} !/admin\.php [NC]
RewriteRule ^([^/.]+)/?$ ?a=$1 [L,QSA]
```

Comment: i am on apache 2.2 ! qsa not supported ! :D

Comment: `QSA` works very well on Apache 2.2 but you can remove `QSA` from last rule.

Comment: some thing appear to be wrong why i should RewriteRule ^(index\.php)?$ /%1? [R=301,L] ? there is another pages that donot use index.php file . it maybe damage them . like support.php which loaded from hort.com/support

Comment: ok so did these rules actually work? If not provide details what URL did you use for testing and what it got redirected to?

Comment: it is so hard to say . because every time i change something maybe affect on other things . it need time to test . but thank you for asking . i am going to test and will reply here .

Answer (score 0):

You can change the first redirect:

```
# Redirect "ugly" URLs to the desired URLs
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \?a=([^\ ]*)
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} !\?a=return_visa [NC]
RewriteRule ^$ /%1? [R=301,L]
```

Comment: not helped . but thanks . i think thr 2 nd pard cause the problem . not the first .